# Why not call methods of a class

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, tabs, extjs4

I have got a TabContainer class. This class is a extend of Ext.tab.Panel.
The create works fine, but, when i try send a message to instance Firebug says:

> "TypeError: tbbar.canAddTab is not a function"

The class is:

```
Ext.define('KMA.view.environment.TabContainer',{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.environmenttabcontainer',

    initComponent: function(){
        [...]
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    createTab: function(aTitle,aToolTip,anItem){
        return {
            title: aTitle,
            itemId: aTitle + "Tag",
            tabconfig: {
                title: aTitle,
                tooltip: aToolTip,
                items: anItem
            }    
        };
    },
    openTabs: function(){
        return this.getItems().length;
    },
    maxOpenTabs: function(){
        return 7;
    },
    canAddTab: function(){
        return (this.openTabs() < this.maxOpenTabs());
    },
    addTab: function(aTabCfg){
        this.add(aTabCfg);
    }
});
```

My example code is:

```
var tbbar = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('environmenttabcontainer');
console.log(tbbar);
console.log(tbbar.canAddTab());
```

In the first "console.log" Firebugs show the instance of TabContainer, and show the methods of the class. But, why not work ?. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing it is not working because `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` returns an array.
This works:

```
var t = new KMA.view.environment.TabContainer();
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('environmenttabcontainer')[0].canAddTab
 > function (){
         return (this.openTabs() < this.maxOpenTabs());
    }
```

Is there a reason why you are using a component query instead of having a direct reference ?